# How to get all listbox item using word vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to get all the list-items of a listbox not only selected.
For example I have a list box with following list item:

```
A
C
K
L
```

How I can show them all in Immediate window?

Comment: Oh ya, I got it. Listbox1.List(0)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that others can find it in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through all by using the column property of a ListBox. This `Column(index, row)` property return the value of the ListBox item at a specific index and row. For your simple ListBox the index will be 0. However, the row must be variable. For example you can use a for loop to get all the values of the ListBox.

```
for i = 0 to ListBox1.ListCount-1
    MsgBox(ListBox1.Column(0, i))
next i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub get_all_list_item()

For i=0 to Listbox1.ListCount-1
Debug.Print Listbox1.List(0)
Next i

End Sub
```